# Problems wxwidgets2.8 compiling on ubuntu mingw64 errors libarary erros

Tags: ubuntu-14.04, wxwidgets

I have executed

```
 ./configure --host=i686-w64-mingw32 --target=i686-w64-mingw32 --enable-unicode
```

on my ubuntu machine. 
and then I ececuted `make`

I went into the sample order `/wxWidgets-2.8.12/samples/animate/` and `make` again.

```
./anitest.exe 
err:module:import_dll Library wxbase28u_gcc_custom.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\jester\\mem_layout_mgr-a8eff49\\toolchain\\wxWidgets-2.8.12\\samples\\animate\\anitest.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library wxmsw28u_adv_gcc_custom.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\jester\\mem_layout_mgr-a8eff49\\toolchain\\wxWidgets-2.8.12\\samples\\animate\\anitest.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library wxmsw28u_core_gcc_custom.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\jester\\mem_layout_mgr-a8eff49\\toolchain\\wxWidgets-2.8.12\\samples\\animate\\anitest.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library libgcc_s_sjlj-1.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\jester\\mem_layout_mgr-a8eff49\\toolchain\\wxWidgets-2.8.12\\samples\\animate\\anitest.exe") not found
err:module:import_dll Library libstdc++-6.dll (which is needed by L"Z:\\home\\jester\\mem_layout_mgr-a8eff49\\toolchain\\wxWidgets-2.8.12\\samples\\animate\\anitest.exe") not found
err:module:LdrInitializeThunk Main exe initialization for L"Z:\\home\\jester\\mem_layout_mgr-a8eff49\\toolchain\\wxWidgets-2.8.12\\samples\\animate\\anitest.exe" failed, status c0000135
```

Yes, I have tried to add `libstdc++-6.dll` in the execution folder... but without success still the same error. (https://www.dll-files.com/libstdc++-6.dll.html I downloade it here.)

I have also already tried to use -static-libgcc and -static-libstdc++ or just -static

Can somebody tell me what is going wrong?

Comment: The libraries are not properly configured. I suggest you download the latest source code of wxWidgets and then compile it.

Comment: How do you run `anitest.exe` under Ubuntu? You seem to be using Wine, have you put the DLLs into a directory where Wine looks for the DLLs?

Comment: $> wine anitest.exe // I call it in the command shell...